# Is there a way to restrict a process with certain name from spawning?

Tags: terminal, unix, launchd

Upon launching, the Reverso app spawns two processes - Reverso (the app itself) and the annoying Reverso Helper, which occupies the menu bar with its icon and remains active even after cmd+Q -ing the main app.

`killall "Reverso Helper"` does kill the unwanted process while keeping the main program intact. However, if the main app remains open for a dozen of seconds, the Helper process gets spawned again.

`ps -o ppid=, -p $(pgrep "Reverso Helper") | xargs ps -p` tells us that the parent process of both Reverso and Helper is `1 /sbin/launchd`, ["the service management framework used by macOS, similar in some ways to systemd on Linux"](https://www.howtogeek.com/319048/what-is-launchd-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-mac/), which is interfaced through a terminal tool launchctl.

I studied the launchctl manual rather superficially and looked for the Reverso Job Defenitions files in specified directories, but didn't find any. I didn't want to dig deeper in this direction.

I feel like I'm missing a more obvious and elegant way to prevent a process with certain name from starting on any Unix-like system, which would be much more useful to know than some macOS-specific stuff. Please, share your ideas.

Comment: Most (maybe all) helper apps have a purpose - be sure you want to remove its functionality. The Reverso helper app is how the Control-C-C shortcut is made available to all apps even when the main Reverso app is not running.

Comment: @Gilby, I know what it _declares_ to be doing in the background. However, I find such behaviour to be annoying and contradictory to macOS UX principles. Every GUI app should be completely cmd+Q -able (except for Finder).

Comment: If you don't like the way Reverso is designed to operate, you could try another similar app - like Translatium.  Many apps have to work with helper processes to conform with Apple's design restrictions.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand your question, you have a problem with the helper respawning while the main application is running. Once you quit the main application you should be able to kill the helper as well.

Answer (score 0):

While you could (in theory) wrap the `exec()` system call to prevent certain paths/names from getting executed, this would be a rather weak protection as any binary can be easily renamed to work around the block.

To prevent an user-installed application from getting launched is to remove all the access rights from it via Terminal.

```
chmod 000 "/Applications/APP NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/*
```

For system applications you can at least pause/stop the process by running

```
killall -STOP "APP NAME"
```

The process will stay but will not take any CPU time any longer. The icon in the menu bar will remain visible though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate on preventing the execution? The menu bar space is too precious to waste :)
I've found one sledgehammer approach to my problem - deleting the Helper app from Reverso's package contents. But I would definitely like to know a more general-purpose method.